# magmi . remove skus from their existing category in website #1 but leave them in website #2

Tags: category, import, magmi

I have over 3000 skus that have already been imported into categories in 2 websites on the same magento db.

I would like to do some kind of import to remove skus from their existing category in website #1 but leave them in website #2. I've tried to find a reference to something like that in the documentation for category on the fly creator plugin. Have only found category_reset column which will either allow for reset in both websites or not. I require something that will reset one and not the other in the same import file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is not possible with MAGMI since it is not possible in Magento itself - at least not when we're talking about `websites`.
It sounds more like you need to set up another store view in order to be able to assign products to its relevante category.
With MAGMI you then can use the `stores` column, duplicate products in your import source and assign categories accordingly.

Example:

```
"stores","sku","categories"
"store1","123","some/category/path"
"store2","123","other/category/path"
```

Another option could be to then work with store category root names (but I'm not sure about this approach):

```
"sku","categories"
"123","[store1]/some/category/path;;[store2]/other/category/path"
```

Comment: Now it is possible???

Comment: @zus - meaning?

Comment: ::I'd say this is not possible with MAGMI since it is not possible in Magento itself :: Now possible?